# DUPLICATE WALLET SAME SEED PHRASE

Tags: solana-program

Please could someone assist me . My STEPN app on the SOL network was hacked and all assets stolen however my wallet attached had a passcode and therefore still exists - I have checked my address on Solscan and see my wallet there with the crypto still intact. The problem is I re-installed the app using the same email address and the app issued me a new address with THE SAME seed phrase. Therefore I have same seed phrase for 2 different addresses is this possible? And how do I recover my first wallet? I have tried to load the first wallet using the seed phrase I was given when I first installed STEPN in March(same seed phrase as the re-installed with different address) into a coinbase wallet app and it restores the new wallet with 0 funds into it? My STEPN account was scammed 4 days ago.

Comment: You are saying you put in your wallet address and you see the assets are still there? What is the address?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - one seed phrase can point to multiple addresses. Though one private key is only associated to one account.

Transactions on the Solana network aren't reversable, so unfortunately it isn't possible to recover your stolen funds.

Answer (score 1):

Get your funds off of that seed phrase ASAP. Generate a new seed phrase and send funds there. Multiple addresses can be associated to a seed phrase, and if they have your seed phrase, they can access all of your wallets, including the one that still has assets.